# IONIC App-Horizontal, scrollable thumbnail slider

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-scope

there is a list of orders. When we click on >(right chevron detail option), it redirects me to order detail page. Order detail page may have a list of items ordered by one person. Each item has camera option to click a picture.

Say there are 2 items each with a camera option, so we will be clicking two pictures- one for each item. And, I want to display both of them in a div as a scrollable thumbnail slider without visiting my phone's storage space for images.  I'm trying display images as thumbnails, somewhat like owl carousal using http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/camera/ 
and now I need to display it as a thumbnail gallery in a  div, immidiately after taking picture. Controller code being used is same as in the above mentioned link document.

```
.controller('CameraCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaCamera) {

  document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {

    var options = {
      quality: 50,
      destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
      allowEdit: true,
      encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      targetWidth: 100,
      targetHeight: 100,
      popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
      saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
      correctOrientation:true
    };

    $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
      var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
      image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
     }, function(err) {
  // error
    });

  }, false);

})
```

Answer (score 0):

By Default ionic will save all the images in the cache directory.
what I have done in my project that I will move the images from cache directory to the SdCard with the filemanager plugin using move file function. As well as I am taking records in the SQL table including the image name and its path so whenever I require I load the records from the table.

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function (event, viewData) {
    ImageService.LoadImages().then(function (list_images) {
        var list = list_images;
        angular.merge($scope.showData, list);
    }, function (rej) {
        console.error(rej);
    });
    /* you can enter the function that you
       want to call every time when view loads, Like above I did */
});
```